# How to manage password in settings.xml of maven in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

We use a `settings.xml` as 'managed file' (Global Maven settings.xml) in Jenkins.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>xxxreleases</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>plaintextpasswd</password> 
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>xxxsnapshots</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>plaintextpasswd</password>
    </server>
    ..
```

It contains passwords for servers and profiles in plain text. How can we encrypt or hide this password in this configuration without editing every Jenkins job (there are many jobs which are using this .xml file and it's working fine).

Comment: Store them into the credentials store of Jenkins...

Comment: @khmarbaise and How can I provide them in the settings.xml?

Comment: Do you use the config file provider plugin in Jenkins? There you can add the entries from the credentials store into the `setttings.xml` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Will this also work for properties like <flyway.placeholders.db.user/password>?

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this is to store the ID and password in the Jenkins Credentials store. Then you can inject the ID and Password into the environment either in a pipeline job using the `environment{}` block like:

```
environment{
    USER_CREDS = credentials('credential_id')
}
```

This will create 3 environment variables USER_CREDS (contains user:password), USER_CREDS_USR, and USER_CREDS_PSW.

With a freestyle job, use the *Credential Binding Plugin* to get the ID and password into the environment. Then you can use Maven's mechanism for accessing environment variables (I believe it is something like ${env.USER_CREDS_USR}).

Doing it this way makes it easy for developers to do local builds as well. They just have to set the environment variables in their local build environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer already, I've deleted the username, password texts which you see in my question and added credentials with the same ID. But will this also work on profiles where we use tags like: <flyway.placeholders.db.user/password>?  (I didn't create this part)

Comment: I don't know much about a maven file, but if you can get the environment variable into Maven I'm sure you can use it to replace bits of text. Otherwise what else is it for?